# Stop certain messages from sending in roblox

Tags: lua, chat, roblox

I am trying to have certain commands (For moderation) not be shown in the roblox chat but still be picked up by Player.Chatted or a similar event.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by editing the Chat Modules. When you test the game, in the `Explorer` tab, go to `Chat`. Copy everything inside the service and click stop on the studio test. Now paste everything into the `Chat` service. (Out of game testing). Head over to the localscript called `ChatScript`, then to `ChatMain`, and finally, open the module script called `MessageSender`. Now on line 15, you will see a function called `methods:SendMessage()`. This is the function that sends a message. Inside this function, you can write any of your moderation commands that you don't want to show. For example:

```
 local modCommands = {"!kick", "!ban"}
 function methods:SendMessage(message, toChannel)
    if table.find(modCommands,message) then
        --Message doesn't send to the chat, however it can still be picked up from a player.Chatted event
    else
        self.SayMessageRequest:FireServer(message, toChannel)
        --Message sends to the chat
end
```